# Создать пустой DIV на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Коллеги, как всегда ознакомился со всеми примерами, не нашел - как правильно сделать пустой DIV "над картой", чтоб **map** был хозяином этого DIV. У меня сложная фильтрация, поэтому стандартные выпадающие списки мне никак, делаю своё меню. Вернее, уже сделал, это меню "поверх" карты, и никак к карте не привязано:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="myMenu" class="myMenu"></div>

Style такой:

    .myMenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100;
    left: 10;
    }
```

Работает, пока не делаешь карту в полный экран или не меняешь вебстраницу. При полном экране мои элементы по понятным причинам не видны.

DIV надо как **sidebar-panel-view** (в нем Погода... Где поесть, Гостиницы, Аптеки, Ещё... Реклама...), только без крестика закрыть.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, наверно правильней всего это реализовать через собственный элемент управления как это сделано тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Хочу скрыть этот слой, сделал заготовку, пока не могу скрыть: https://jsfiddle.net/Yuraz/05h4hsov/

Comment: Кажется в этом случае проще удалить контрол с карты myMap.controls.remove(customControl); https://jsfiddle.net/q61enn0o/

Comment: Очень оригинально, а главное просто, в принципе подойдет, спасибо! А для перспективы, вот узнать бы, как все таки создать свойство Visible в свой класс, я думал он должен унаследоваться, но вроде как нет ничего подобного в моем созданном объекте.